# AS3 CustomEvent not being extended at all?

Tags: actionscript-3, custom-event

I get some weird errors when creating CustomEvent, it appears Event being extended does not give access to Event properties:

```
package 
{
    import flash.events.Event;
    public class CustomEvent extends Event
    {

        //public static const COMPLETE:String = 'complete';

        private var _assetName:String;
        public function get assetName ():String
        {
            return _assetName;
        }
        public function set assetName ( aname:String ):void
        {
            _assetName = aname;
        }

        public function CustomEvent (type:String, bubbles:Boolean = false, cancelable:Boolean = false)
        {
            super (type, bubbles, cancelable);
        }

        public override function clone ():Event
        {
            return new CustomEvent(type, bubbles, cancelable) as Event;
        }
    }
}
```

When doing:

```
myObj.addEventListener(CustomEvent.COMPLETE, objLoaded);
```

I get error that COMPLETE doesnt exist... Ok, i set it to the place and then it caomplains about cannot convert CustomEvent to Event.

What am i missing here ??

Comment: COMPLETE  does not exist you have it commented out.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare this `public static const COMPLETE:String = 'complete';` as static var/const are not transfered to extending classes.

The error about converting CustomEvent to Event may be caused by setting event listener to listen to the `Event` not `CustomEvent`.

Comment: I think this is the right answer for this. There is something strange in line "return new CustomEvent(type, bubbles, cancelable) as Event;"

Comment: When you add event listener, you provide `Event.type` value (a `String`) and not `Event` (a `Class`). So the class casting is irrelevant in this case, because we're talking about compiler errors, not runtime errors.

Comment: Yes, I shortened my thought. I was thinking about the listener AND consequently event handling function.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the event dispatched and what does the signature of the listener look like?

Answer (score 0):

We've got a few issues to cover here:

1. You have your `public static const COMPLETE`... commented out. Why? That's needed if you want to refer to `CustomEvent.COMPLETE` as the event type.
2. Using my psychic third eye, you've got your event listener declared like this:

   ```
   public completeListener(evt:Event):void
   ...
   ```

   That's not going to work the way you want it to. You need

   ```
   public completeListener(evt:CompleteEvent):Void
   ...
   ```
3. Unrelated to the compilation issue, your custom event has another issue. Your clone method is not going to clone the `assetName` property. Try something like this:

   ```
   public override function clone():Event
   {
       var ret:CustomEvent = new CustomEvent(type, bubbles, cancelable);
       ret.assetName = assetName;
       return ret;
   }
   ```